# Hibernate: Is there a way to automatically convert native SQL results to a custom object?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a native SQL query that returns several computed results (such as sums and averages from several tables) and I want to load these results into a custom object that contains all the necessary fields. I'm aware that Hibernate provides the `addEntity` method, which allows you to specify the type of mapped entity that your results represent.

In this case, since the results are taken from several tables, the custom object that I'm using is not a mapped entity. Is there a way to make hibernate return a `List<CustomObject>` or will I have to manually copy the results to the proper objects? Thanks.

```
Query query = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString.toString());

return (List<CustomObject>)query.list(); //doesn't work, obviously
```

Comment: why aren't you using hibernate query?

Comment: The mappings have many eager fetchings (these are convenient in other parts of the application) which resulted in a lot unnecessary joins and data fetching that caused a visible performance hit. There are many tables involved and I thought that the cost of tweaking all the fetch strategies was just not worth it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [result transformers](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/). They are designed to do exactly what you are looking for and work for both HQL and SQL.